# What can we do with "too old to migrate" questions that belong on meta?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I was looking for a specific post I'd seen before on golfing tips: [Tips for golfing in Perl?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/tips-for-golfing-in-perl)

I eventually found it on [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), not [meta.codegolf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) where it obviously belongs. Yet, apparently it is too old to migrate to meta.codegolf. I have read [the reason for this on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days) but I disagree that it's applicable here.

What are the options to be able to find such content solely by searching on [meta.codegolf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: [tag:tips] questions do belong on main if that's what you mean. Meta is *solely* for discussing the site an it's contents. [tips] is not about the site itself

Answer (score 11):

[Tips for golfing in Perl?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5105/tips-for-golfing-in-perl) does *not* belong on Meta.

This is because Meta is for questions about the site *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf*, not for questions about Perl.

Furthermore, our [help center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that

> Non-challenge questions that are are related to solving programming puzzles or a particular type of challenge are also on topic.

which means that they are, in fact, on topic on the main site.

Comment: maybe someone could take this occasion to correct `that are are related` into `that are related`, or even just `related`...

Comment: @plannapus [meta-tag:status-completed]